# Перенести игру с Unity 3D на Android

Tags: windows, c#, android, sdk

Я создал игру на движке *Unity3d* и теперь хочу ее перенести на *android*. Что-то нужно устанавливать еще, подключать, переделывать?  Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я думаю, перенести ничего не изменяя не получится...
Вот тут инструкция по интеграции юнити в андроид сдк:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

Кстати, интересная тема! Надо будет и себе попробовать...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, создали - в смысле десктопная версия? Мне кажется там нужно будет только заморочиться с управлением.

Answer (score 2):

Для того что-бы сбилдить (собрать) под андроид проект достаточно просто в настройках билдинга выбрать соответствующую платформу. Также понадобится установленный JDK и Android SDK. Когда будете первый раз билдить, *Unity* попросит указать путь к Android SDK. После билдинга вы получите `*.APK` файл, который нужно просто скопировать на ваше устройство и установить.

А вот дальше могут начаться проблемы и зависят они от того, что у вас в проекте.

Что может случится:

1. Интерфейс — размеры экранов мобильных устройств меньше чем у компьютеров, поэтому некоторые кнопки и поля могут оказаться слишком мелкими. Просто сделайте их больше размером.
2. Управление — возможно придется переписать управление под мультитач (multi touch).

Если ваш проект ориентирован как на Android, так и на PC то можете использовать директивы компилятора: **[Платформенно зависимая компиляция](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)**

Например вы можете написать так:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    // управление для андроид, этот
    // кусок кода будет билдиться
    // только для андроида
#endif

#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
    // управление для windows, этот
    // кусок кода будет билдиться
    // только для windows
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

*Не считайте ответом, но из-за отсутствия нужно привилегии не могу редактировать (дополнять) чужие ответы.*

**Дополнение к ответу:** 
Вообще необходимо сделать несколько непростых шагов:

1. Установить "Unity Remote Tool" c Play.Market или AppStore (в зависимости от ОС).
2. Оптимизировать управление под ваш(и) аппарат(ы). Тут пригодится 1 пункт.
3. Оптимизировать быстродействие приложения.
4. Оптимизировать приложение под разные разрешения экрана.
5. Оптимизировать вес .apk файла.
6. Отдать на тест друзьям/QA специалистам.